# Conflicting Window and Local Resource in WPF Application

Tags: wpf, templates, styles, themes

In coding a WPF application I used a ListView and defined an template as a resource at that level:

```
<ListView IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CardViewTemplate}">
    <!--ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CardViewTemplate}" -->
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CardViewTemplate">
            <GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=Product Name}" Width="290" BorderThickness="4" FontSize="14"
                    FontStyle="Normal" Padding="10" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="12"
                    UseLayoutRounding="True">
                <StackPanel Name="stackPanel1">
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="wrapPanel1">
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock MinWidth="80" Text="{Binding Path=Product
                                                             Name}" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"
                                    TextAlignment="Center" />
                        </WrapPanel>
            </GroupBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

This works perfectly however when I use a Resource (Expression Dark) at the Window Level the ListView appears blank.

Any suggestions as to what could be the cause? I have tried everything I could think about

Comment: What do you mean with "[...] when I use a Resource (Expression Dark) at the Window Level [...]"? Did you try to use another theme? Or do you mean Expression Blend with its Dark Theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple reasosns...

1. Is your `ListView` directly under your `Window`?
2. If your `Dark` template correctly configured?
3. Does it apply if you directly set it under the list view (without static resource reference)...

   ```
    <ListView>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:Key="CardViewTemplate">
             ...
         </DataTemplate> 
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
   ```

?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Tried applying it directly by setting it under the listview as you showed but got no change. So I commented out the ListView style in the template and it showed up. So its the template, just not sure which property/s exactly.

Answer (score 0):

> when I use a Resource (Expression Dark) at the Window Level

Themes do not work properly at the window level. Or what exactly are you *doing*?

Comment: I actually applied the theme at the window level. What would be the better way to apply this?

Comment: @dsgrant07: `Application.Resources`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. When I apply it at the application level the initial problem recurs. The listview is blank although the theme doesn't define a style for listviews and the style is applied directly at that listview. Any suggestions?

Comment: @dsgrant07: Maybe the theme is broken, i don't know, not enough information to suggest anything...

Answer (score 0):

There is a (several) problem with the ExpressionDark. template.

For the empty row problem, modify the theme after the following line:

```
    <GridViewRowPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Margin="0,2,0,2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

By adding a ContentPresenter afterwards:

```
    <GridViewRowPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Margin="0,2,0,2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <ContentPresenter />
```

I had the same problem and found the solution here:
http://bogdanvarlamov.com/2011/01/21/expressiondark-wpf-theme-listview-problem/

The more I use ExpressionDark the more problems I'm finding with it, and the more I think about moving to a better theme!